# File API: Returns file reference (object) or whole file content (string)?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, fileapi

In the plupload (plupload.html5.js), I see this code:

```
// Blob is string so we need to fake chunking, this is not
// ideal since the whole file is loaded into memory
if (typeof(blob) == 'string') {
    chunkBlob = blob.substring(chunk * chunkSize, chunk * chunkSize + curChunkSize);
} else {
    // Slice the chunk
    chunkBlob = blob.slice(chunk * chunkSize, curChunkSize);
}
```

And I wonder if that blob can be a string? As I can see from the source that blob variable should contain (I think it should contain) the file reference to a file selected by user, so it expresses something like this:

```
<input type="file" onchange="var thatBlob = this.files[0]" />
```

From the comments I see that it may return the whole file content rather than a reference to it. How come?

Is there something I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I missed it out that they also use getAsBinary() (that returns string).